# Implementing Steam login using openid in django for google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, openid, steam

I have followed the steps on the [Google App Engine](https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django-openid/). **What should I do now?** I can't find tutorials on implementing Steam OpenID in django, with Google App Engine. I have looked at a sample solution in Flask [Flask Snippets](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/42/). It doesn't help much as I have little knowledge in flask and the openid for flask

I am planning on modifying the LoginPage function inside `openidgae/views.py`. I would have this method redirects the http request to `http:// api.steampowered.com/< interface name>/< method name>/v< version>/?key=< api key>&format=< format>`.

What is "version"?

And how do I receive the returned json package?